# Special characters in smarty (with jquery too)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, character-encoding, smarty, special-characters

In my Database i have some special characters stocked (french accent) as : **ç**

When I want to print them with smarty it goes perfectly showing : **ç**

Problem is when i'm mixing some jquery (and jquery ui (autocomplete) with smarty, it just shows the code `&ccedil;`

How can I tell smarty to show **ç** instead of the encoded version **ç**
Here is my script and here is link to the page : http://www.entendu.info/contactus

My php file :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * from members";
    $executequery = $conn->Execute($query);
    $members = $executequery->getrows();
    STemplate::assign('members',$members);
?>
```

My template file (part of)

```
{literal}
        <script>
        $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {/literal}{section name=me loop=$members}"{$members[me].username}",{/section}{literal}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 3

    });
});
</script>{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have auto-filtering enabled in Smarty. Try the `nofilter` flag as per the doc:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl

```
{$members[me].username nofilter}
```